# How to set "full graphics" on 11.04

Tags: 11.04

I could originally change the graphics to be really "flashy" on 10.10 but now there is no option to. The graphics driver IS working fine also.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're referring to the Visual Effects tab in the Appearance applet in Ubuntu 10.10 and earlier versions, which had the options None, Normal, and Extra. I gather it isn't compatible with Unity, which is why it is missing.

An option that is still available is to install compizconfig-settings-manager, available in the Ubuntu repositories, which allows for a lot of optional special effects and tweaking, including some specific to Unity. There was a comment by Mark Shuttleworth that some of those special effects are buggy under Unity.